# Better approach for assigning object's properties to a listview?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, listview

My code works fine but I am looking for a simpler solution to my application. I have an object model `Person` with 3 properties `int Id`, `string Name`, `int Mode`. That will be its property for now to keep it simple but I guess it might reach up to 15 properties.

I am fetching the contents from a database helper.

```
Person n = db.GetPersonByName("hello");
List<string> str = ConvertObjectToStringList(n);

for (int i = 0; i < str.Count; ++i)
{ 
    dataContentListView.Items.Add(str[i]);
}
```

I am converting the contents manually.

```
private List<string> ConvertObjectToStringList(Person person)
{
    List<string> str = new List<string>();
    str.Add(person.Id.ToString());
    str.Add(person.Name);
    str.Add(person.Admin.ToString());
    return str;
}
```

I firmly believe this is not the best solution so if you can think of something else please let me know.

EDIT 1:

I am using Universal Windows Application

EDIT 2: ***(SOLUTION I USED)*** Mong Zhu suggested to use data binding. This is better since my code will be cleaner and my xaml will handle how it will be displayed.

```
<ListView x:Name="restaurantListView" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="217" Margin="341,284,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="674">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Admin, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: do you use Winforms or WPF or something else? Is the `ListView` supposed to show always only one `Person` ?

Comment: im using Universal Windows App and yes, just one person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection for this.

```
using System.Reflection;


private List<string> ConvertObjectToStringList(Person person)
{
    List<PropertyInfo> pi = person.GetType().GetProperties(
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();

    return pi.Select(x => x.GetValue(person).ToString()).ToList();            
}
```

Explanation:

This will scan for all properties and get the value of each `public` instance property as a string into a `List<string>`.

The advantage here is that you don't need to care if further properties might be added in future. They will show up on your list.

If you would use a `ListBox` you could simply bind the list as `DataSource`:

```
listBox1.DataSource = ConvertObjectToStringList(pers);
```

Comment: Hmm glad you pointed out the binding. I came up with another approach, I just decided to use `dataContentListView.Items.Add(n);` and use data binding on the xaml page

Comment: @Gibs sounds good, may be you can also post your solution for future users. Might be that someone will also decide to go down this road that you chose. Peace out.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Person pr = new Person();
List<string> str = pr.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p =>  p.GetValue(pr).ToString()).ToList();
```

It will convert all properties to List of strings

Comment: You should take care with simple reflection, the performance might be very slow

Comment: I do agree that point. But if he wants all properties to be converted a string list and want to avoid the pain of doing manually whenever new property added reflection would be good. Also it depends on the application. If it is something simple then the performance may not be noticable

Comment: "It will convert all properties to List of strings" unfortunately not, it will collect all the property *names* into a list

Comment: Ohh sorry you are correct. I have edited the answer. Thanks to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not very important the simple reflection version is much easier to understand, but if performance is important, you should consider using expression trees which can be compiled to IL at runtime. These will give you the benefit of not having to write the code but give you great performance  (you should test but I'm talkin 20 times faster)

Here how I would solve your problem:

```
public class Program
{
    public static string ConvertToString(object value)
    {
        return value == null ? null : value.ToString();
    }

    // We cache the adders they are expensive to create but fast to execute, create once use many times 
    public static Lazy<List<Action<Person, List<string>>>> PropertyAdders = new Lazy<List<Action<Person, List<string>>>>(() => CreateAdders<Person>());

    public static List<Action<T, List<string>>> CreateAdders<T>()
    {
        // The convert to string method we use for converting the property value to a string
        var converterMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("ConvertToString");
        // The add method of the list
        var addMethod = typeof(List<string>).GetMethod("Add");
        // Array of actions one for each property in the object
        var result = new List<Action<T, List<string>>>();
        foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            //We want to create a lambda that essentially looks like this:
            // (o, list) => list.Add(ConvertToString((object)o.Prop));
            // We create the two lambda parameters
            var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var list = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<string>));

            // We create the actual lambda expression 
            var adderExp = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, List<string>>>(
                Expression.Call(list, addMethod, // Call to list.Add
                    Expression.Call(converterMethod, // Call to Program.ConvertToString
                        Expression.Convert( //Conversion of property value to object
                            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(item, prop), // member acecss o.Prop
                        typeof(object))
                    )
                ), item, list
            );

            result.Add(adderExp.Compile());
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static List<string> ConvertObjectToStringList(Person person)
    {
        List<string> str = new List<string>();
        foreach (var adder in PropertyAdders.Value)
        {
            adder(person, str);
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ConvertObjectToStringList(new Person { Admin = 1, Id = 1, Name = "adas" });
    }
}
```

Comment: If libraries are OK and performance is really a factor, you could take it a step further and use [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) to skip the expression compilation overhead and just use an efficient get/set value by property name access to each property.

Comment: @Dan The library looks interesting I personally haven't used it, but took a look at the code and they use dynamic methods under the hood as well.

Comment: I recently had a WPF setup that necessitated property binding using [ITypedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) and arbitrary property access underneath, in my profiling I found FastMember to be the fastest out of Reflection, Linq Expressions, and FastMember.  As well as the cleanest code.  So its worth looking into if you are running into any efficiency gated reflection situations.